# How to connect using ssh in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, ssh

How do I setup a ssh connection in Laravel so that I could access remote machine and run commands on it from backend controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel developers have created a simple way to do some simple tasks on remote servers that integrades directly with Laravel. It's called Envoy and uses Blade syntax. More can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/envoy).